# ImageResizer - Watermark display issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, watermark, imageresizer

Using the watermark plugin, I would like to create images with different sizes of overlay. For this, I set the **Width** and **Height** attributes of the ImageLayer object (**ic**) but the watermark does not appear on the resulting image.

How to go about this?

My code looks like this.

```
ic.Align = ContentAlignment.BottomRight;

ImageResizer.Plugins.Watermark.DistanceUnit unit =
    new ImageResizer.Plugins.Watermark.DistanceUnit(100.0, DistanceUnit.Units.Pixels);
ic.Width = unit;
ic.Height = unit;

ResizeSettings rs = new ResizeSettings("stretch=fill");
ic.ImageQuery = rs;

wp.NamedWatermarks["img"] = new Layer[] { ic };
```

Comment: Do you add "watermark=img" to the ResizeSettings instance at some point? Perhaps you could include more code and context?

Comment: The problem is that the application does not execute at first but reiterating it results in the desired watermark. I am not sure if this is caused by the config instance. Calling the script in Page_Init does not help, either.

Comment: We don't have enough code to see if you're using local or global Config instances. Can you include everything?